# Bot won't react after seeing a word contained in a word list

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot react to every message containing words like hey or hi, but when I send a message containing one of those, it does nothing, here is my code:

```
const words = [
    'hey',
    'Hey'
]

client.on('message', () => {
   if (message.content.includes(words)) return message.react("")
})
```

There are no errors in the console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

```
message.content.includes(words)
```

is equivalent to

```
message.content.includes(words.toString())
```

which actually checks if the string joining the `words` array by a comma exists in `message.content` (not what you want). In your case, it does the following:

```
message.content.includes('hey,Hey') // words = ['hey', 'Hey']
```

[`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) returns a string joining the array elements by a comma.

#### Solution

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the words in the `words` array is present in the message content. And you don't have to add the capitalized word forms to `words`. It's enough to only add lowercase words and use [`String.prototype.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to lower case the message content before checking if any of the entries in `words` exists in the content.

```
const words = [
  'hey',
  // ...
]

const content = message.content.toLowerCase()
const shouldReact = words.some((word) => content.includes(word))
if (shouldReact) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It fixed my problem.

Comment: @Zariaa_ You're welcome. You might also want to ignore bot messages (`message.author.bot`).